# Will adding a new fetch request template to Core Data break previous versions of model?

Tags: ios, core-data

I want to add a new fetch request template to a core data model. I know I could do it programmatically, but all the other fetch request templates are present in the core data editor and it makes sense to add the new one alongside them.

My question is, since this is part of a point release for an app that has been in the store for quite some time already, is there any chance this will break existing installs? Does it count as some kind of migration, or not? Obviously we will QA it, but I'd like to know the answer in advance, and googling has been fruitless so far.

Comment: Why not just make a new version of the model anyway? It's good practice and not much effort.

Comment: Fair point, but there are commercial reasons why we want this point release to be as benign as possible. The core data models we have are very complex and the QA cycle involved in testing a migration would be costly.

Comment: Then the only way to find out is to try :). You should know immediately. Lots of changes don't break the model - for example, adding new default values to attributes is fine. I don't see why a fetch request would affect it, because that's nothing to do with the persistent store.

Comment: Sure, I already did try it: it seems to work OK with no asserts. But our client's user base has lots of stored data and I kind of wanted to be sure.

Comment: I've added an answer with the best backup I could find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not stated explicitly anywhere, but in the `NSManagedObjectModel` documentation, it says the following:

> **Changing Models**
>
> Since a model describes the structure of the data in a persistent store, **changing any parts of a model that alters the schema renders it incompatible with (and so unable to open) the stores it previously created**. If you change your schema, you therefore need to migrate the data in existing stores to new version (see Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide). For example, if you add a new entity or a new attribute to an existing entity, you will not be able to open old stores; **if you add a validation constraint or set a new default value for an attribute, you will be able to open old stores.**

It doesn't explicitly mention fetch requests, but these don't have anything to do with the schema, so I think you'll be fine.

Comment: Yes, I read that document before I posted the question. I agree it seems to _imply_ that adding a new fetch request in the model will not invalidate the earlier version, but I was looking for some explicit confirmation. I'll update this question with my findings after our QA is complete.

Comment: @Echelon did you eventually get your answer? I am dealing with the same question...

Comment: @MiMo I've accepted this answer because in the end it did not cause a problem, so I think it is OK to add fetch requests.